# Save XAML Image into file in metro apps

Tags: c#, pdf, bitmapimage

i convert a PDF file to BitmapImage in C#. After i manipulate it (resize, rotate) and i want to save it to new PNG or JPEG file but i'm not found how can i make that. I'm developed a windows store apps in C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this blog post: [Save XAML as PNG in a Windows Store App](http://loekvandenouweland.com/index.php/2013/12/save-xaml-as-png-in-a-windows-store-app/)

You should be able to do this using the class [BitmapEncoder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapencoder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), the method BitmapSource.CopyPixels will give you the pixels data that BitmapEncoder requires.

Answer (score -1):

Use [LibPdf](https://code.google.com/p/lib-pdf/), for PDF to Image conversion

This library converts converts PDF file to an image. Supported image formats are PNG and BMP, but you can easily add more.

Usage example:

```
using (FileStream file = File.OpenRead(@"..\path\to\pdf\file.pdf")) // in file
{
    var bytes = new byte[file.Length];
    file.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    using (var pdf = new LibPdf(bytes))
    {
        byte[] pngBytes = pdf.GetImage(0,ImageType.PNG); // image type
        using (var outFile = File.Create(@"..\path\to\pdf\file.png")) // out file
        {
            outFile.Write(pngBytes, 0, pngBytes.Length);
        }
    }
```

}

[ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/), you should also look at this freely available and powerful tool. It's capable of doing what you want and also provides some .NET bindings (as well as bindings to several other languages).

Comment: I want to use Windows.Data.Pdf, with this library i can put my pdf in the BitmapImage but i don't know how can i put my bitmapImage into the JPEG file.

Comment: I strongly believe that LibPdf will not work on the heavily restricted  API of Windows Store apps. And for ImageMagick, I am 200% sure it cannot be used at all. On top of that, these are both GPL libraries, meaning that they cannot be used for free in commercial closed-source applications, which is in general the case for Windows Store Apps.